# Read file at server boot

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony4

I'm starting on a project with Symfony 4 and
I would like to have a JSON file in which I would store some static JSON strings.

**When the server starts, it should read the JSON file and let the content be accessible throughout the project.**

I was hoping to find some kind of Symfony starting file in which I would open the JSON file and parse it but I can't find anything like this.

If someone know the right way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `server boot` ? you mean Symfony server ?

Comment: Yes I do ! Because I want the parsing to be done only once.

Comment: you may go as work around with `--router` [option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html#command-options)

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results by using a [Symfony Cache Warmer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-cache-warmer) - A class that implements a specific interface (`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerInterface`) and is tagged (`name: kernel.cache_warmer`).

You would read the file during bootup, likely happening while you are deploying your site, and write the output to cache, or as a serialised PHP file that can be easily included.

Note that the warmer might not be run every time, so it would be useful to make it a thin layer around a service that performs the conversion/writing, and have that available in case the data isn't available.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'll check that out ! Though I find it odd that something so simple as loading data on boot would be that complicated !